# Knockoutjs array.length is makes the whole javascript stop working

Tags: knockout.js

I am learning knokcout.js

I was using the example in http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html, which is working fine.

I added the following to the javascript there.

```
viewModel.breads = ko.dependentObservable(function() {

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function(item) {
            return item.category()=='Bread';
        });

}, viewModel);
```

It was working.

Then I added the follwing

```
viewModel.breadsLength = ko.dependentObservable(function() {

        var filtered_array= ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function(item) {
            return item.category()=='Bread';
        });

        return filtered_array().length;

}, viewModel);
```

This makes the whole javascript fail. I tried `filtered_array.length(), filtered_array().length(), this.breads.length()` etc. I was not able to get it to work.

Displaying array length by  `data-bind="text: breads().length"` works only once and does not seem to update whenever I use a new json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you would just want to do: `filtered_array.length`.  The result of `ko.utils.arrayFilter` is a normal array and you would be checking the `length` property of it (which is not an observable).

Comment: I used `filtered_array.length`, and bound it to a html span using `data-bind`. It works but only once. It is not updating whenever the JSON from back end changes. `breadsLength` is a `dependentObservable`, yet it does not update itself on the page. What am I doing wrong? `viewModel.breads` works perfectly well whenever there is an update

Comment: Can you put your updated code in the question or in a jsFiddle?  If your `breadsLength` computed observable is basically the same code as your `breads` and just returns the length, then there is no reason that it should not be updated when any dependencies change.

Comment: I have noticed something. Till now I was putting the <span> inside a <h2> element. If I put the <span> element elsewhere it works. How is that possible?